# Using variable to fetch json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

Is it possible to use a variable to fetch a JSON object? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var test = "json_category";
alert(json.test);
```

I don't have the option to do `json.json_category` so that's not an option. I need to use the variable to represent the string. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to write

```
alert(json[test]);
```

Comment: This did it for me. I was actually using the brackets I was also using a dot though so my code looked like this alert(json.[test])

Answer (score 6):

I *think* you're looking for the following:

```
var foo = {
    'bar': 'baz';
  },
  key = 'bar';

alert(foo[key]); // baz
```

Objects can be referenced using bracket notation (`['property']`) or using dot notation (`.property`); Both of these are valid:

```
foo['bar'] // baz
foo.bar    // baz
```

Comment: Normal called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), not array notation.

Comment: i was about to ask if its actually called array notation
so its bracket notation,thx  i wondered  how this is called normally